# Function returning type depends on keyof interface put as argument

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, return-type

I have a function `getThing` that should have its first argument be a lowercase name of a class and the return type an instance of the class itself or `null`. It also has a second argument for "searching" the class in it (internal code, not important here).

For example, if I do `getThing('user', "the content")`, it should return me `User | null`

But I couldn't find how to manage to do this, so for now I have one overload for each possible input, but it's very long and complex to read, so I'm asking if there is a better way to do it ?

For now, I have something like this, but it doesn't work at all :

```js
interface Type {
    channel: Channel;
    command: Command;
    emote: Emoji;
    guild: Guild;
    member: GuildMember;
    message: Message;
    role: Role;
    user: User;
};

async function getThing<T extends keyof Type>(datatype: T, content: string | Message): Promise<Type[typeof datatype] | null> {
    switch (dataType) {
        case 'channel':
            return new Channel();
        case 'command':
            return new Command();
        case 'emote':
            return new Emoji();
        case 'member':
            return new GuildMember();
        case 'message':
            return new Message();
        case 'role':
            return new Role();
        case 'user':
            return new User();
    }
}

async () => {
    const test = await getThing('command', 'test');
};
```

When hovering over "test", it says `Channel | null` which is correct, but in the function all the `new Something()` are wrong because TypeScript is waiting for `Channel & Command & Emoji & Guild & GuildMember & Message & Role & User`, which is not what I want :/

[TS Playground here](https://tsplay.dev/mpl57m)

Comment: I think you'll have to cast. Try `getThing<T extends keyof Type, R=Type[T]>(datatype: T, content: string | Message):Promise<R | null>` and then  `return new Channel() as unknown as R`

Comment: Try function overload